# Kendo SearchBar - Order by StartsWith then Contains

Tags: kendo-ui

Say I have 3 jobs
1.Scientist
2.Data Scientist
3.Developer Scientist

Then in kendo searchbar while searching for the term "Scientist"
The result should be in the order like below
1.Scientist
2.Data Scientist
3.Developer Scientist

But Iam getting the result as below, which is wrong
1.Data Scientist
2.Developer Scientist
3.Scientist

Thanks for the answer in advance

Answer (score 1):

The search bar provides only a filtering mechanism. The sorting functionality of the grid is separate and you should set it accordingly. However, if you would like to still have the sorted items you should implement your own sorting mechanism.

If you sort the items in descending order, you will receive them as "1. Scientist 2. Developer Scientist 3. Data Scientist". This is because the second letter of the Data scientist is "a" and comes before "e", hence, in descending order "Developer" will be shown before "Data".

If the custom sorting sounds like a plausible option to you, use the following option of the grid:

[Custom sort function declaration](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.sortable#columnssortablecompare)

Please note that this would work only if you are using client-side operations.